# Show that choosing any rational number in (0,1) has probability 0.

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

In the above proof, why is the last step necessary:

[image]

Why isnt saying that the probability of  any one number being chosen is 0, enough to prove that the probability of choosing a rational number is 0?

Is it because if two rational numbers have different probabilities associated, the total probability would be  more than 0? I think I just answered the question myself, but I just want to make sure I'm understanding this right.

Comment: You’re being asked to compute the probability that a random point chosen *is rational*, not the probability of choosing a rational point. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The probability of picking a rational number in the segment $ [0,1] $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823421/the-probability-of-picking-a-rational-number-in-the-segment-0-1)

Comment: @William So youre saying that I have to prove that the probability of all rational number between 0 and 1 is 0. Not just of one particular. Thats why I have to add them up, to show that.

Comment: @EthanBolker Unfortunately not this particular question. I think atleast not. Ive read it several times.

Comment: @swisstackle Exactly, as the probability that a given point $\alpha \in \Omega$ satisfies property $Q$ is precisely $\mathbf{P}[\{x \in \Omega : x \text{ is } Q\}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexey's answer is correct, but I'm going to delve a bit into the motivation. The basic idea is that we want to preserve our intuition that the probability that either of two disjoint events $A$ and $B$ happen is equal to the sum of the probabilities of the individual events:

$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)
$$

By induction, we can extend that to any finite collection of events:

$$
P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + \cdots + P(A_n)
$$

if $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ are disjoint. But what about the union of an infinite number of events? If the probability that a random variable $X$ equals a *particular* rational number $r$ is equal to $0$, regardless of which rational number we pick, what about the probability that $X$ equals *any* rational number? Given that we can enumerate the rational numbers—say, $r_1, r_2, \ldots$—can we claim the following?

\begin{align}
P(X = r_1 \cup X = r_2 \cup \cdots)
    & = P(X = r_1) + P(X = r_2) + \ldots \\
    & = 0 + 0 + \cdots \\
    & = 0
\end{align}

Note that unlike the previous rule, this requires us to be able to decompose a composite event into an infinite number of individual events (outcomes, in this case), and to add the probabilities accordingly.

This is what we need countable additivity for—because the rationals are countably infinite. Note that this does *not* work for the irrationals, which are uncountable. Probabilities are not uncountably additive. We can see that quite clearly in this case, because if the probability of choosing a rational value is $0$, then the probability of the complement—choosing an *irrational* value—must be $1$, even though the probability of choosing any particular irrational value is $0$ (just as it is for any particular rational value).

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote, so that I can improve the answer?

Comment: I have no idea. I found your answer the most helpful one so far. Youre saying just because choosing a particular rational number has probability 0, doesnt mean that all of them have probability 0. In order to show that all of them have probability 0, we have to add the probability of every single one of them up. In some way, everybody here is saying the same thing though. Including William and @Alexey. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @swisstackle: No, they all have probability $0$; the issue is more about how many zeros you can add up and still end up with zero. You can add up any finite number of zeros, and you always end up with zero; this is not controversial. But if you have an infinite number of zeros you're adding up, do you end up with zero? It turns out to depend on the countability of the number of zeros you're adding up (among other things). If it's *countable*, then you are sure to end up with zero as the sum—that's countable additivity. But if it's *uncountable*, you *might* end up with zero—but you might not.

Comment: @swisstackle: I should emphasize that this rule applies strictly to probability. Different rules may apply in different circumstances. (However, there are analogues to this rule in other contexts. Your mileage may vary, etc.)

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and since $(0,1)$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, the probability of choosing any particular number in $(0,1)$ is undefined.  However, since we are looking at $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ in our case ($\mathbb{Q}$  is countable), additivity applies and therefore we can say that the probability is 0 when adding up the 0's. This leaves me with one question: Doesnt this contradict the axiom that $P(S) = 1$?

Comment: @swisstackle: No, the probability of picking any number in $(0, 1)$, rational or not, is exactly zero. ¶ As for your other question, $P(S)$ cannot be evaluated just by looking at the rationals—$S$ includes an uncountable number of irrational values too—so countable additivity does not contradict $P(S) = 1$.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought that $S$ only includes the events of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$. Makes sense now. Thanks! Math gets "weird" with infinity.

Answer (score 2):

It's important that the union is countable. When looking at uncountable unions the probability can be above 0. The simplest example is:

$$ (0, 1) = \bigcup_{r\in(0,1)} \{r\} $$

And of course $\mathbb{P}(\{r\})=0$ but $\mathbb{P}((0,1))=1$. The axiom of additivity is just a formal way to say that when looking at a countable union (of disjoint sets) the probabilities do just add up (and to 0 because all of them are 0 in this case).